# Joining of tables is working but the select query is giving issues in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables which i have joined in spark. I am trying to run a select operation on the result of join dataframe. The joins are successfull but the select operation is throwing exception.

i have tried splitting up the final joins (select operation contains 3 joins). But still the exception remains.

```
val a = "select * from db.tbl1"
val b = "select * from db.tbl2"

val df1=  hive.executeQuery(a).toDF()
val df2=  hive.executeQuery(b).toDF()
val df3=df1.as("d1").join(df2.as("d2"), ($"d1.col1" === $"d2.col1"))

df1.as("bs").join(df2.as("ds"),($"bs.col1" === 
$"ds.col1"),"left").join(df3.as("inf"),(($"ds.col1" === $"inf.col1") && 
($"ds.col2" === $"inf.col2") && ($"ds.col3" === 
$"inf.col3")),"left").select($"bs.col1",$"bs.col2",$"bs.col3",$"ds.col4
",$"inf.col5").show()
```

I am getting the below error message:

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
        at org.apache.spark.sql.vectorized.ColumnarBatch.column(ColumnarBatch.java:98)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.datasourcev2scan_nextBatch_0$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)

Comment: So if you are executing .show() without that select all is fine?
have you tried that ? `val df3=df1.as("d1").join(df2.as("d2"), Seq("col1"))

df1.as("bs").join(df2.as("ds"),Seq("col1"),"left")
.join(df3.as("inf"),Seq("col1","col2","col3")),"left").show()`

Comment: I am getting error for the below command df1.join(df2,Seq("key_1"),"left_outer").show

Comment: @chlebek : we have tried to select all without show. That also throw array out of bound exception. Tried with the seq logic as specified in your comment. Got same error.

Comment: could you paste here output of df1/df2.printSchema() and .show(5) here? It may help to solve your problem